# Odd GUI hang in Java app on OSX

Tags: java, macos, core-graphics

We have a large graphics intensive app written in Java.
On just a small percentage of OSX machines, we are seeing odd GUI hangs.

The GUI just stops responding for up to 5 minutes or so.

Looking at our logs, the App is still running and doing things.  Looking at the OSX system log, we see several errors like this, per second for what appears to be the duration of the hang:

kernel  virtual IOReturn IOGraphicsAccelerator2::newUserClient(task_t, void *, UInt32, IOUserClient **): Too many contexts (398) or command queues (0) created, possibly leaking?

The number of contexts built up to around 444.
What operation could we be doing in Java to cause those?

OSX 10.13.4, Oracle Java 1.8.0_161